# How do I delete all but 10 newest files in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to keep a directory full of log files manageable. Nightly, I want to delete all but the 10 most recent. How can I do this in a single command?

Comment: have a look at logrotate

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024088/linux-save-only-recent-10-folders-and-delete-the-rest

Comment: @michael How can mine be a duplicate of that one, if my discussion was created first?

Comment: @ovaherenow "yours"? I don't see your name on either question, so I'm not sure which you mean. My comment doesn't even indicate which is a duplicate of the other.  But it doesn't matter -- it's just a comment, with a link. It could be added to either question, or both questions. It's up to someone else -- an admin -- to mark one or the other as a duplicate. No nefarious sleight was intended nor should any be perceived. More important than which question was first, is which question has the best answer -- again, the link facilitates this discussion, it doesn't determine the answer.

Comment: @michael wow.  That is really odd.  This thread was opened by me but that's obviously not my user name.  But I am getting notified about this thread.

Comment: @user746532: You cannot accept an answer to this question, or comment on it, because there is no obvious evidence that you originally asked it. If you and user75814 are the same person, go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles.”

Comment: Many answers here form a "parsing `ls` extravaganza". Readers please see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 76):

For a portable and reliable solution, try this:

```
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

The `tail -n -10` syntax in one of the other answers doesn't seem to work everywhere (i.e., not on my RHEL5 systems).

And using `$()` or ``` `` ``` on the command line of `rm` runs the risk of

1. splitting file names with whitespace, and
2. exceeding the maximum commandline character limit.

`xargs` fixes both of these problems because it'll automatically figure out how many args it can pass within the character limit, and with the `-d '\n'` it will only split at the line boundary of the input. Technically this can still cause problems for filenames with a newline in them, but that's far less common than filenames with spaces, and the only way around the newlines would be a lot more complicated, probably involving at least awk, if not perl.

If you don't have xargs (old AIX systems, maybe?) you could make it a loop:

```
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | while IFS= read -r f; do
  rm -f "$f"
done
```

This will be a bit slower because it spawns a separate `rm` for each file, but will still avoid caveats 1 and 2 above (but still suffers from newlines in file names).

Comment: @HaukeLaging: From the `head(1)` man page: `-n, --lines=[-]K print  the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file`

Comment: On Solaris 10 `head` and `xargs` give errors. Correct options are `head -n 10` and `xargs rm -f`. Full command is `ls -1tr ./ | head -n 10 | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: Note the `ls -1tr` is the number ONE not the letter "L".

Comment: It should also be noted that newlines are rare but valid characters in ext filenames.  This means that if you have the files "that", and "that\nthing", if this script hits "that\nthing", it'll delete "that", error when it couldn't delete "thing", and leave "that\nthing" (the intended target) unaffected.

Comment: @Synthead I believe I "noted" that fact fairly clearly in my post. Do you have a better solution that also accounts for newlines in filenames which is portable and simple?

Comment: `xargs -d` and a negative number for `head`  are GNU extensions, so it's not really portable outside of GNU systems. It still has issues with filenames contain newline characters or starting with `-`. Note that the command to read a line is `IFS= read -r line` in POSIX shells, not `read line`.

Comment: Good points. I'm not sure the best way to get around the `xargs -d` and negative number for `head` issues in a purely POSIX way. I'll edit the `rm` and `read` commands. As for files with newlines, I did explicitly say those would be an issue, and the working around this issue would be quite a bit more complicated. Since filenames containing newlines are very rare in practice, this shouldn't be a problem in >90% of cases. In fact, I would argue that if you have a system that creates filenames with newlines, you should go home and think long and hard about your life.

Comment: I'm not sure this totally works.  The assumption is that there are already 10 files present.  This doesn't work if there are less than 10 files I think.

Comment: @ovaherenow Using "`head -n`" with a negative number won't print anything unless there are more than the number of lines specified. So, if there are only 5 files, `head` won't print anything. Try it yourself: create a text file with 5 lines, and run "`head -n -10 _file_`" and you should see no output.

Comment: @ovaherenow it can be made to work with empty results if you pass the `-r` (`--no-run-if-empty`) option to `xargs`.

Comment: @Walf ls -1tr is the correct solution given the behavior of head when given a negative value for -n.

Comment: @IsaacFreeman I've deleted my bad advice, cheers.

Answer (score 23):

The code you'd want to include in your script is

```
 rm -f $(ls -1t /path/to/your/logs/ | tail -n +11)
```

The `-1` (numeric one) option prints each file on a single line, to be safe. The `-f` option to `rm` tells it to ignore non-existent files for when `ls` returns nothing.

Comment: Original poster, here. I tried this command, but it doesn't work--I get the error "rm: missing operand"

Comment: Did you use the correct path? Obviously `/path/to/your/logs` is just made up for you to enter the correct path. To find the bug execute the parts `ls -t /path/...` and `ls -t /path/... | tail -n +11` alone and check if the result is correct.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I am quite sure you got something wrong. Mind the `+` before the number. It makes `tail` not print the last n elements but all elements beginning from the n'th. I checked in again and the command should definitely remove only elements older than 10 most recent files under all circumstances.

Comment: @halo Indeed, sorry.

Comment: Using `$()` and ``` `` ``` on the commandline, especially with a command that lists filenames runs the risk of splitting filenames with spaces in them in to separate arguments. See my answer below for a safer and more portable solution.

Comment: I think your answer is very dangerous `ls` prints a file name, not a path so your `rm -f` will try to remove the files in the current directory

Comment: @DanielBöhmer see @Jürgen-Steinblock reply above; this script only works if it is run from the directory in which the files exist, because `ls -1t` does NOT print the full path.

Answer (score 22):

Apparently parsing [`ls` is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

If each file is created daily and you want to keep files created within the last 10 days you can do:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime 10 -delete
```

Or if each file is created arbitrarily:

```
find /path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%Ts\t%P\n' | sort -n | head -n -10 | cut -f 2- | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: `-mtime 10 -delete` only deletes files modified exactly 10 days ago. Older files will not be deleted. `-mtime +11 -delete` will delete files that have been modified 11 or more days ago leaving the last 10 days of log files.

Comment: I think the use of `%p` instead of `%P` is needed on the `printf`so that the files got have the full path. Otherwise the `rm -rf` does not work.

Comment: -delete also kills the directory not only the files within

Answer (score 10):

A tool like logrotate does this for you. It makes log management much easier.  You can also include additional cleanup routines such as halo suggested.

From `man logrotate`:

> **logrotate** is designed to ease administration of systems that generate large numbers of log files. It allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and mailing of log files. Each log file may be handled daily, weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large

Comment: I can't find where user "halo" (currently going by the username [Daniel Böhmer](https://superuser.com/users/56756/daniel-b%c3%b6hmer)) suggested additional cleanup routines. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 4):

I modified [Isaac's approach](https://superuser.com/a/554512) a little bit.

It now works with a desired path:

```
ls -d -1tr /path/to/folder/* | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash you can try:

```
ls -1t | (i=0; while read f; do
  if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then
    ((i++))
    continue
  else
    rm -f "$f"
  fi
done)
```

This skips the 10 newest als deletes the rest. logrotate may be better, I just want to correct the wrong shell related answers.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://pdaddy.wordpress.com/2007/03/02/shell-script-to-delete-all-but-the-n-newest-files-in-a-directory/):

```
#! /bin/sh
# keepnewest
#
# Simple directory trimming tool to handle housekeeping
# Scans a directory and deletes all but the N newest files
#
# Usage: cleanup <dir> <number of files to keep>
#
# v 1.0 Piers Goodhew 1/mar/2007. No rights retained.


if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 <dir> <number of files to keep>"
  exit 1
fi

cd $1
files_in_dir=`ls | wc -l`
files_to_delete=`expr $files_in_dir - $2`
if [ $files_to_delete -gt 0 ]; then
  ls -t | tail -n $files_to_delete | xargs rm
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "An error ocurred deleting the files"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "$files_to_delete file(s) deleted."
  fi
else
  echo "nothing to delete!"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. While providing code like this is helpful, it also helps to provide some additional information about how it might be used or what the code does. You can use the [edit] button to make future improvements to your post.

Answer (score 1):

not sure this will help anyone but to avoid potential issues with wonky characters i just used `ls` to perform the sort but then use the files `inode` for the delete.

For current directory, this keeps the most recent 10 files based on modification time.

`ls -1tri | awk '{print $1}' | head -n -10 | xargs -n1 -t -Iinode find . -inum inode -exec rm -i {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

I agree that parsing ls is evil!

Ensure only the last 5 files are kept in the `/srv/backups` path.

```
find /srv/backups -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%Ts\t%P\n' \
    | sort -rn \
    | tail -n +6 \
    | cut -f2- \
    | xargs -r r
```

Comment: This is the best solution here simply because it doesn't parse the output of _ls_. (It does have a problem if you have newlines in your filenames though, eek!)

Answer (score 1):

On my Synology NAS I slightly modified [@h0tw1r3's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1424762/1495862) to make it work in a scheduled task and to handle possible blank and/or newline characters in the file name by zero-terminating the generated strings:

```
find /path/to/backup/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%Ts\t' -print0 \
| sort -rnz \
| tail -n +11 -z \
| cut -f2- -z \
| xargs -0 -r rm -f
```

**IMPORTANT**: This will delete any matching files! I strongly recommend doing a test run first by replacing the last command `xargs -0 -r rm -f` with `xargs -0` which will echo the matching files instead of deleting them.

A short explanation of each step:

1. `find /path/to/backup/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%Ts\t' -print0`
   [Find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) all regular files (`-type f`) in the backup folder without traversing any subfolders (`-maxdepth 1`), print (`-printf`) the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (`%Ts`) of the last modification followed by a tab character (`\t`, used in step 4) and the full file name followed by a null character (`-print0`).
2. `sort -rnz`
   [Sort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) the zero-terminated items (`-z`) from the previous step using a numerical comparison (`-n`) and reverse the order (`-r`). The result is a list of all backups sorted by their last modification date in descending order.
3. `tail -n +11 -z`
   Print the last lines ([`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)) from the previous step starting from line 11 (`-n +11`) considering each line as zero-terminated (`-z`). This excludes the newest 10 files (by modification date) from the remaining steps.
4. `cut -f2- -z`
   [Cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) each line from the second field until the end (`-f2-`) treating each line as zero-terminaded (`-z`) to obtain a list containing the full path to each backup older than 10 days.
5. `xargs -r -0 rm -f`
   Take the  zero-terminated (`-0`) items from the previous step ([`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)), and, if there are any (`-r` avoids running the command passed to xargs if there are no nonblank characters), force delete (`rm -f`) them.

Answer (score 1):

the solutions with

```
find /Users/test/delete/*.zip -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

have one caveeat:

if you do daily backups and run this command before writing backups to folder where store backupfiles (exmaple qcow2 files),
and do for longer time no backups, maybe 12 or longer days
the command will erase "ALL" kept old backups beacuse they are older then "10" days....

i think a method like this (listed above) :

```
ls -1tr $PATH_TO_DELETE/* | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

is the better way in this case

just my 2 cent

Answer (score 0):

I needed an elegant solution for the busybox (router), all xargs or array solutions were useless to me - no such command available there. find and mtime is not the proper answer as we are talking about 10 items and not necessarily 10 days. Espo's answer was the shortest and cleanest and likely the most unversal one.

Error with spaces and when no files are to be deleted are both simply solved the standard way:

```
rm "$(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7')" 2>&-
```

Bit more educational version: We can do it all if we use awk differently. Normally, I use this method to pass (return) variables from the awk to the sh. As we read all the time that can not be done, I beg to differ: here is the method.

Example for .tar files with no problem regarding the spaces in the filename. To test, replace "rm" with the "ls".

```
eval $(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7 { print "rm \"" $0 "\""}')
```

Explanation:

`ls -td *.tar` lists all .tar files sorted by the time. To apply to all the files in the current folder, remove the "d *.tar" part

`awk 'NR>7...` skips the first 7 lines

`print "rm \"" $0 "\""` constructs a line: rm "file name"

`eval` executes it

Since we are using `rm`, I would not use the above command in a script! Wiser usage is:

```
(cd /FolderToDeleteWithin && eval $(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7 { print "rm \"" $0 "\""}'))
```

In the case of using `ls -t` command will not do any harm on such silly examples as: `touch 'foo " bar'` and `touch 'hello * world'`. Not that we ever create files with such names in real life!

Sidenote. If we wanted to pass a variable to the sh this way, we would simply modify the print:

```
print "VarName="$1
```

to set the variable `VarName` to the value of `$1`. Multiple variables can be created in one go. This `VarName` becomes a normal sh variable and can be normally used in a script or shell afterwards. So, to create variables with awk and give them back to the shell:

```
eval $(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7 { print "VarName="$1 }'); echo "$VarName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Isaac Freeman response, but working on any directory:

```
ls -1tr $PATH_TO_DELETE/* | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

You can also set a prefix, like `$PATH_TO_DELETE/testFi*`

If you use `*` after the `PATH` `ls` will output absolute file names, at least in "my" bash :)

Answer (score 0):

Using negative argument in head/tail is not always compatible. This is Isaac's solution with tail instead.

```
ls -d -1t /path/to/file/filename*.ext | tail -n +11 | while IFS= read -r f; do
  sudo rm -f "$f"
done
```

Works in FreeBSD 13.1

Answer (score -1):

You can delete file with specific name pattern and numbers of day old using

```
find /Users/test/delete/*.zip -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Above command deletes files matching pattern `/Users/test/delete/*.zip` and which are 10 days older.