# Length of range in bash

Tags: bash, debian

I'm trying to delete some files in a directory using some commands.
Using loop
`for i in $(ls -tr $path); ...`
i need to know length of
`$(ls -tr $path)` 
How to get the number of files in directory $path without using one more loop?

The very problem is to delete the files in the folder. The resultant folder have to contain no more than 10 most recent files.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do, and what you mean by "length"

Comment: In a directory I have 14 files. How to get count of them without using one more looping?

Comment: Uh, **please** [don't do `for i in $(ls ……)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) – why so complicated? Just do `for i in $path`. The first variant will break as soon as files have whitespace in their name. Unless of course you're trying to solve a different problem, in which case it would be preferable if you asked about [*that* other problem instead](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Can I make a guess, you are trying to delete the newest or oldest *n* files in a given directory, or some variant of that problem? :)

Comment: @slhck updated the post. You are right)

Comment: I thought so. See the duplicate question here: http://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -l $path | wc -l
```

ls -l will give you one line per file, wc -l counts the number of lines.