# How do I delete 10 newest files in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

similiar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux), I want to delete the 10 newest files.
(Since the recent files contain error while the previous files are ok)

The answer from linked question (only keep the 10 newest file) is

```
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

Comment: There are many answers to the linked question. Have you tried to understand at least one of them and adjust it to your needs (working with some expendable set of files for testing purposes). What happened? What failed? Where are you stuck? ([edit] the question and tell us). This would be reasonable research effort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete all but 10 newest files in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux)

Comment: A little tip: Most answers to [the linked question](https://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux) use `head` to show only the first results, `tail` to only show the last results and reverse the order of `ls` with the `-r` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of the top answer to that question is:

```
ls -1t | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

Note the removal of the `r` flag to ls means it is sorted normally instead of in reverse